# Word for stealing an item then returning it without the owner's knowledge?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-requests

Does there exist a specific word to describe the action of stealing an item, keeping it for a few days then returning it from where it was taken?

An example: A friend of mine "lost" his personal diary for few days while in the college hostel. Someone (unknown to the owner) was definitely interested in reading about his life story. He found the diary on the table after a week. So someone stole it temporarily and gave it back.

Is there is a specific term or phrase to describe this action performed by the person who stole and later returned the item?

Edit: Thought I clearly posted the question. But this has turned out to be something totally different. The question is just about the action of the person who used the item and replaced it without the owner's consent. I don't think my example really captured what I wanted to ask.

Assume that a person is in need of an item and so he searches for it. The person finds the item somewhere then steals it and leaves the place and remains a silent observer. He uses the stolen item for his personal gain and also looks out what's happening in the place where he stole the item. The owner of the item and friends start searching for it and they don't get it. Now this person feels like he might get caught or he might have finished using the item as long as he wants and he stealthily places the item in its original place when the owner is not around. This has nothing to do with the owner's memory. I am just asking about the action of the person who stole it initially and then replaced it.

If **borrow** is the word for it, then the owner should be able to say, "A person **borrowed** my precious item without my consent." But I don't know if it captures the stealing intent of that person. I hope I made it clear.

Comment: If the situation involved a car it would be called [joyriding](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/joyride). I don't know if there is a similar term for other items.

Comment: ***"borrowed"**?*

Comment: @bradimus That just means stealing and riding recklessly right? It doesn't answer my question of returning the car.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When someone borrows, the lender knows that they have given the item to the person who borrows. But here the case is totally different. Someone stole the item instead of borrowing. Am I right?

Comment: That's why I put it **"in quotes"**. But it's a common facetious usage in the "unauthorized" context.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Okay. In this case, keeping it in some place where the owner of the item can find the item. If there are flaws in my question, feel free to edit it. I just want people to understand the scenario so that I can get an answer.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear exactly what's being asked here. Is it specifically that the *method of returning* the stolen item consists of leaving it somewhere the owner is bound to find it? Is it significant that the owner *might* think it had never actually been stolen at all (maybe he just didn't notice it when he was looking for it before)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Consider the case where a person actually took it without the owner's knowledge and kept the item without the owner knowing about it. The owner finding it or not finding it is not the important part of the question. The question is to find a suitable word or phrase for the action performed by the person who stole the item. Is it clear now?

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan: Not really. I don't see how it could not  make any difference whether the owner "finds" the borrowed/stolen item later or not (or by implication, whether he ever even *knew* it was temporarily missing). How would this "action performed by the thief" differ from someone slipping a memory stick into your laptop and copying off all your passwords (i.e. - without you knowing)? Or hacking into a website's "secure server" and doing something similar (where they might be well aware there *had* been a security breach)? That's not "borrowing".

Comment: Ah! Okay. Got it. Sorry for not being clear. The owner finds the item and he didn't have any memory lapse. Consider that a person actually took it, used it for sometime and kept it without the owner's knowledge.

Comment: NagarajanShanmuganathan , the thing that is confusing people is your use of the word 'keep' and 'kept', When you say, "a person actually took it, used it for sometime and kept it without the owner's knowledge." this means the item is never returned, the owner never gets it back. This is called "stealing". However, if you say, "a person actually took it, used it for sometime and then gave it back", it means that the item was returned, the owner has the item again. This could be called "borrowing", as @FumbleFingers says, either facetiously, or between two people who have a close relationship.

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan unfortunately, it appears that someone obtained personal and private information on your friend, without receiving his consent so to do. In this case, no proof exists that the diary was taken without permission, so all that can be done is to keep the diary safely under lock and key to avoid a recurrence.

Comment: Similar question : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35070/is-there-a-word-for-accidentally-stealing-something

Comment: @Eilia No. The scenario here is totally different. The person is not accidentally stealing.

Comment: If you 'borrow' something *without* permission, but with an intention of returning it later, it is technically not theft, but you can still be prosecuted and convicted of larceny or theft. This is because *nobody* knows your true intentions but you. It legally becomes theft when your ***intent*** changes, but again, nobody knows your intent but you so that is why you can still be prosecuted. This is described in more detail in this article http://criminal-law.freeadvice.com/criminal-law/white_collar_crimes/no_return_owner.htm

Comment: I'm pulling my hair out because I'm almost certain there's a perfect portmanteau for this and I can't remember it of find it by searching _teh interwebz_

Comment: @TecBrat Ah! You'll get the word soon!

Comment: It's called temporary taking or temporary theft. However, for it to be theft, there has to be conviction. That said, the unbeknownst to the owner part is just that. Of course, it doesn't work for perishables...ha ha. https://consumerist.com/2013/10/02/when-is-taking-someones-phone-not-considered-theft/

Comment: The word "joyride" means to steal (often temporarily) a motor vehicle and use it for one's pleasure.  It is too specific to serve as in all circumstances the OP is looking for, but is closely associated with the concept he  described.

Comment: If a lighter (joking) tone can be used and the intentions should be kept out of the way, I would suggest: **temporarily relocated**. (I have no references, so I provide only a comment, not answer)

Comment: You should say:"A person borrowed **a personal** item without my consent.*"

Comment: @Greybeard Does that automatically imply that the person returned the item without my knowledge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, ***Indian taking***

> Indian taker
>
> *Informal. Offensive* A person who steals your property but returns the stolen property to you at a later date.
>
> *The car thief stole my car but was nice enough to return it the next day. What an Indian taker piece of shit.*
>
> [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=indian+taker)
>
> Indian giver
>
> One who takes or demands back one's gift to another, as in *Jimmy wanted to take back Dan's birthday present, but Mom said that would make him an Indian giver.* This term, now considered offensive, originally alluded to the Native American practice of expecting a gift in return for one that is given. [; early 1800s]
>
> [The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/indian-giver?s=t)

Comment: This answer hurts me since I am an Indian. :P Anyway, I think this is the best answer!

Comment: "Indian taker" is not a common term.

Comment: I've never heard this and would have no idea what it meant

Answer (score 10):

*Here's an expanded version of my [earlier comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315371/word-for-stealing-an-item-then-returning-it-without-the-owners-knowledge/315390?noredirect=1#comment715728_315390), as [suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315371/word-for-stealing-an-item-then-returning-it-without-the-owners-knowledge/315390?noredirect=1#comment716042_315390). The dictionary definitions are straightforward and some have been provided by others. I'll just link to them as necessary rather than print them in full here.*

There are two actions here: taking the item, and then bringing it back. Based on the title, what happens to the item in between those two actions is provided as background knowledge but outside the scope of this question.

The first action is *[theft](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/theft)*, and the question's clarifying edit makes it explicit that it is *[stealing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/steal?q=stealing)*.

Since the item is returned, it can also be said to have an element of *[borrowing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/borrowing)*, except that *borrowing* casts it in a more innocent light than warranted.

The *owner* might charitably consider the whole activity to be **unauthorised borrowing**. To someone who knows the facts as presented in the clarifying edit, it is the **theft and [return](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/return)** of the goods.

Comment: In the UK at least "theft" requires the intention to [permanently deprive](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/60/crossheading/definition-of-theft)

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for shedding light on UK law. In the OP's clarifying edit, the person who took the item only returned it to avoid getting caught. That suggests the initial intent included permanent deprivation. Returning the goods later doesn't change the initial intent. If this was a real account, further investigation would be justified. As a story told from an omniscient point of view that labels the miscreant's actions as *stealing*, the initial act was *theft* as the word is commonly used and, as the story seems to suggest, in the legal sense also if UK law applies.

Comment: Drawing on my law background, I believe that the unsatisfying gulf between theft-and-return and unauthorized borrowing is what the law calls _mens rea_: the intention of the thief/borrower at the time of the taking. In law, as mentioned bellow, this gulf is bridged by the act of "conversion," but that term is not understood by a lay audience. Therefore, and adjective or adverb with one of the above phrases could tweak the phrase to the desired level of malfeasance. Something as simple as malicious borrowing covers some of the elements, but it doesn't address the covert actions.

Answer (score 7):

Stealing and then returning it is of course stealing. If the thief has a bad conscience and returns the goods, or is afraid that he or she may be found out and returns the goods, it is still stealing. I assume that you meant "Taking something away without permission or knowledge of the owner and later returning it".

This will have some legal consequences, which will be depending on where exactly you live. It might be legally theft, it might not. Some places have special laws for joyriders who take a car, drive around, and will always claim they intended to return it, so this is illegal and punished the same as theft, even if it isn't.

But we are talking about language, not about laws. You can call it whatever you like even if it doesn't match the laws of your country. You can say "To me, it's stealing, I don't care what the law says", if that's what you think. In written language, you can call it "borrowing" in quotes, including the quotes, because it is similar to borrowing but you are not convinced that it is the same.

The "diary" case I would call a severe violation of the privacy of the diary owner. Compare it to another diary owner who has bought a new diary for 2017 already and that empty diary gets stolen and not returned; that diary owner will probably be a lot happier than the one whose full diary with personal notes was taken away and returned.

To avoid confusion, you can say "Someone took X away without my permission and returned it three days later". Then everyone knows what you mean. As long as you don't know the situation, it's hard to say more. I have two neighbours, one is quite Ok, but I hate the other one. If A asked for my lawn mower, they would get it. B wouldn't. Now my lawnmower disappears for a day and returns. It makes a difference to me whether A or B took it.

Comment: Yes. I was just expecting a phrase for "Someone took X **away without my permission and returned it Y days later**". If there is nothing short to capture this, then I will have to use the sentence as it is. I thought there would be some word to describe this surreptitious action performed by the person who stole in the first place. I just wanted a word which captures both the action - stealing and returning. Not to concentrate on any one particular action.

Comment: +1 for mentioning joy-riding, which is as close to this concept as I can find in an english idiom.

Answer (score 7):

I would be tempted to use the verb *misappropriate*. This gives the idea that the thing was wrongfully or deviously taken, but does not necessarily imply that the thing was stolen. We can also say that the item was misappropriated if it was given back later. *Misappropriate* really means to come into possession of through wrongful means, but it does not stipulate that the thing is kept forever, or that it was necessarily stolen.

We should note, however, that the verb *misappropriate* does not imply that the thing be returned to its owner. Nonetheless, it  seems to be an appropriate verb given the circumstances.

Here is the definition of *misappropriate* from [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/misappropriate):

> **misappropriate**
>
> Pronunciation: /mɪsəˈprəʊprɪeɪt/
>
> **VERB**
>
> **[WITH OBJECT]**
>
> > Dishonestly or unfairly take (something, especially money, belonging to another) for one’s own use:
>
> - *the report revealed that department officials had misappropriated funds*
>
> **More example sentences**
>
> - *After the high increase in council tax and an exceptional increase in essential services costs in rural areas, to give £1m or even £0.5m of our taxes to this project is misappropriating our money.*
> - *It was essentially a sort of collaboration across both things and I completely reject the view that I was misappropriating money.*
> - *He talked about the Government misappropriating money, which is theft.*

Comment: Does one misappropriate a diary? "His diary was misappropriated" ....? What about a lost pair of sunglasses, an umbrella, or a suitcase or any *object* you purposely steal? Do thieves misappropriate stolen money? Although it is a great word, it doesn't fit with the OP's scenario.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, you can misappropriate a diary, a shirt, money, jewelry an idea, pretty much anything. We wouldn't say that a bank robber misappropriated his loot because of the violence involved. Otherwise you can misappropriate anything you like. Admittedly it's often used in a sightly tongue-in-cheek sense when applied to something trivial.

Comment: So someone finds/takes a diary, keeps it a few days then returns it, and that is misappropriation? If I read someone's personal diary in secret, I am misappropriating it? http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=misappropriation&l=0 I really don't think so. And if it's tongue in cheek, then you should say so in the answer. E.g. [He said he has found no evidence that any money was misappropriated or embezzled.](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=misappropriated&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't see what the reading has to do with it. but if you take the diary without permission, then you misappropriated it, before giving it back. Yes.

Comment: None of the ODO citations support this interpretation or usage, The vast majority of citations in the two links I posted use it in connection with funds, aid, or money. To use someone else's  money for one's own personal *advantage*, *gain* or *profit* is to use it  in an inappropriate  manner.  That's my understanding.

Comment: @Mari-LouA So, if you look carefully in and amongst your examples, you'll see the misappropriation of hairdriers, cadavers, pens, ideas, lyrics, names and so forth. The fact that this word is used millions of times a day with regard to money is neither here nor there.

Comment: And if you had read my comment carefully, you would have seen "vast majority" :) BTW Gnasher's answer is probably the best out of the lot.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But I'm suggesting a non-vast-majority more colourful usage! :-)

Comment: I agree with @Mari-LouA. As of now, the most convincing answer is Gnasher's. I hope there is a phrase that captures the scenario.

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan there isn't one, if there had been it would have been suggested days ago. Either use air quotes (a gesture using two fingers on each hand) when speaking, or speech marks to suggest that you know what you're saying isn't technically correct i.e. "borrow". Theft-by-finding is the correct technical term if the person/thief hadn't brought back the object. Out of curiosity is there a term in your native language?

Answer (score 4):

It is called [stealing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steal).

> To take (the property of another) without right or permission;  to take (the property of another or others) without permission or right, esp. secretly or by force. (AHDEL/Random House, TFD)

Some define stealing by intent (the intent being not to return the item.) If the intent is to return it, the word [borrow](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/borrow) applies:

> to take and use (something that belongs to someone else) for a period of time before returning it (MW); to obtain or receive (something, such as money) on loan for temporary use, intending to give it, or something equivalent or identical, back to the lender (AHDEL, [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/borrow))

Borrowing usually implies asking, but not always, especially if the owner is unavailable at the moment.

In your case, I think **"borrow"** with quotes, as offered by @FumbleFingers" (or, to surreptitiously borrow) would be the best answer.

Comment: I *think* "borrow" is probably the best term for OP's context, but I can't help noticing that both you and I are being careful to include "scare quotes" for that usage. By implication, we *know* we're stretching the meaning a bit (in speech, you might add some "unnatural stress" or wiggle your fingers as "air quotes" to make your meaning crystal clear). That's to say ***borrow*** doesn't *precisely* fit without some more-or-less-explicit non-verbal associated element of communication. There probably isn't a well-known verb with ***exactly and only*** the required "unauthorised" sense here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree completely. I think that comes from our ethical stands though. Some people might think nothing of borrowing without permission (a few dollars, a pack of cigarettes, the car) from someone with the intent to replace if they weren't available to ask, so borrow may still fit. But the scare quotes are a must for me, because "borrowing" someone's diary is shady under most all circumstances.

Comment: +1 Perhaps *unauthorised* borrowing would fit, but it's really *stealing and then restoring/returning* if there wasn't some prior understanding to allow it.

Comment: There's still a bit of a problem with OP's *specific* example, because even though the actual ***diary*** is returned (with or without the owner ever knowing that it had been taken), the thief still has the ***information*** (secrets he obtained access to by reading it). It's not meaningfully possible to "return" the "privacy" that was obviously what the thief really stole. But I'm not yet clear on whether it's central to OP's context that the thief was just making temporary ***use*** of something subsequently returned, in order to *really* steal something else accessible through it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, like "Borrowing" a key so that I could open your safe and take the money out of it. You have the key back, so everything is fine,,, right?

Comment: @Karl: What if I'm the only person on the planet who knows how to make and administer an elixir giving me eternal life - but I don't want anyone else to gain this knowledge, so I keep both the potion and the instructions in my safe. Is everything fine if you crack my safe and steal just *a copy of the instructions?* Bear in mind that even if you cover your tracks well, sooner or later (perhaps millions of years in the future! :), I'll probably notice that you're still around, so I *will* eventually become aware that I was "robbed".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I believe you have just conceived a fantastic screenplay!

Comment: @Lawrence I would post *unauthorized borrowing* as an answer.

Comment: @dwjohnston Ok, done. :)

Comment: @medica *Surreptitious borrowing* seems good. But I don't know if people can really understand if I say that in a sentence.

Answer (score 4):

The legal term is called "conversion." That is, someone "converted" your item to his use.

Conversion differs from stealing insofar as the "lost" item is eventually returned to the owner after it was used by the converter. Whereas "stealing" is done with the intent, or at least the effect, of permanently depriving someone of something.

For instance, if someone "pinches" your car, takes a "joyride" with it, and then returns it to your driveway, that would be "conversion."

Comment: +1, however, the definition and legal application of this term varies widely. In the South, it got tangled up with slavery, where a person who hired an escaped slave was chargeable with property conversion. This was to discourage the hiring of escaped slaves. The result is a very convoluted set of case law regarding conversion. I gather that when it used these days, it is almost exclusively with regards to misappropriating money, not property.

Answer (score 3):

He ***sneaked*** the diary.

I think stole is too strong, because he returned the diary; I think "borrow" is too weak, because he did not provide full restitution -- he retained knowledge he was not meant to have.

(1) **sneak** according to [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sneak) is:

> make off with belongings of others
>
> Synonyms: abstract, cabbage, filch, hook, lift, nobble, pilfer, pinch,
>   purloin, snarf, swipe.  Type of: steal  take without the owner's consent

The same reference also says:

> The word sneak has many shades of meaning, but all involve doing
>   something in a secretive or stealthy way.

The villain of the OP's example behaved in a sneaky fashion, both in taking the diary and in returning it.

A full sentence describing the example would be:

> A sneak took my diary and sneaked it back a week later.

(If you go to my source, you will find sneak as a noun and sneak as doing something furtively, in addition to the definition I posted above.)

Answer (score 2):

I would say 'borrowing' over 'stealing', primarily because the question title has an added element of "then returning it".

Here's a movie clip showing a clear contrast between 'stealing' and 'borrowing':
[Captain America clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mESEFrhI9sQ)

The clip starts with this conversation:

> **Natasha Romanoff:** Where did Captain America learn how to steal a car?
>
> **Captain America:** Nazi Germany. And we're borrowing. Take your feet off the dash.

Answer (score 1):

The most accurate single-word term for a situation where a finder discovers an abandoned item but *permanently* maintains possession of it, is called **[theft-by-finding](http://www.yourdictionary.com/theft-by-finding)**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theft_by_finding) provides a succinct definition

> **[Theft by finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theft_by_finding)** occurs when someone who chances upon an object which seems abandoned takes possession of the object but fails to take steps to establish whether the object is abandoned and not merely lost or unattended.* In some jurisdictions the crime is called "larceny by finding" or "stealing by finding"

Having said that, if the finder returns the object at a much later date, the owner might comment that somebody  had "forgotten" to return the diary.

> [Can I Be Accused of Stealing Something I Borrowed If I **Forget to Return It**?](http://criminal.findlaw.com/criminal-charges/accused-of-stealing-something-borrowed.html)
>
> Anyone can make the honest mistake of forgetting to return a borrowed item, no matter how aggravating it might be for the rightful owner. And while the person from whom you borrowed the item may wonder whether he or she may ever receive it back, your actions do not amount to theft if you just **merely forgot to return the item**. From a legal perspective, in order to be accused of stealing, or theft, you would need to have had the intent to never return the item to its rightful owner.

In the situation described by the OP, and not summed up in the question title, as  long as the property is returned to its rightful owner, the person who "found" the item cannot be accused of stealing.

In @medica's answer, she is correct in saying

> Borrowing usually implies asking, but not always, especially if the owner is unavailable at the moment.

However, a lender knows or can guess who the borrower is even if that person hasn't asked permission. For instance, a son/daughter may "borrow" one of his parents' car keys without permission. If neither the car keys nor the child are at home, the parents usually understand what has happened.

In the OP's scenario, no one knows who "found" the diary, and they don't know if the finder read the contents of the diary. Where is the proof?  The person who "lost"  their diary never found out who replaced it back a week later. Someone who finds a coin in the street and pockets it, hasn't borrowed money, they have kept it for themselves. If someone finds a twenty euro/dollar/pound note lying somewhere, and they do not attempt to find its rightful owner, the finder has effectively taken in possession something that was not legally theirs to take.

> **A criminal charge of theft** (or larceny) **generally requires the specific intent to permanently deprive another individual of his or her property.** If you legitimately forgot to return a borrowed item to its rightful owner, then you lacked specific intent to steal the item. As with other specific intent crimes, much stronger and more credible evidence is required in order for the prosecution to establish guilt. -

Source: http://criminal.findlaw.com/

Comment: The point being that the OP's friend doesn't *know* if his diary was stolen, or if the finder "forgot" to return it back.

Comment: I think 'borrow' would sound as a good excuse .....I'd call it a "dispetto".

Comment: Keeping lost items is often theft. Keeping abandoned items isn't. I abandon items that I don't want anymore. You are free to keep abandoned items, but not lost ones.

Comment: @gnasher729  a sizeable amount of money is never abandoned money, and a diary left on a table could said to be abandoned, the point is the "finder" didn't keep it. S/he returned it, late, where s/he found it.

Comment: it might be called surreptitious borrowing.

Answer (score 1):

[Run away with something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/run-away-with#run-away-with__3):

> to steal something, or to borrow something without asking

Answer (score 0):

Requisition?

req·ui·si·tion
ˌrekwəˈziSH(ə)n/
noun

1.
an official order laying claim to the use of property or materials.
"I had to make various requisitions for staff and accommodations"
synonyms:   order, request, call, application, claim, demand
"we have submitted our requisition for additional staff"
verb

1.
demand the use or supply of, especially by official order and for military or public use.
"the government had assumed powers to requisition cereal products at fixed prices"
synonyms:   commandeer, appropriate, take over, take possession of, occupy, seize, confiscate, expropriate
"their house was requisitioned by the army"

or maybe Appropriate?

ap·pro·pri·ate
adjective
əˈprōprēət/

1.
suitable or proper in the circumstances.
"a measure appropriate to a wartime economy"
synonyms:   suitable, proper, fitting, apt, right; More
verb
əˈprōprēˌāt/

1.
take (something) for one's own use, typically without the owner's permission.
"his images have been appropriated by advertisers"
synonyms:   seize, commandeer, expropriate, annex, arrogate, sequestrate, sequester, take over, hijack More

2.
devote (money or assets) to a special purpose.
"there can be problems in appropriating funds for legal expenses"
synonyms:   allocate, assign, allot, earmark, set aside, devote, apportion
"we are appropriating funds for these expenses"